# Loop horizontal scrolling of two divs with mousewheel and buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, frontend

I need to loop horizontal scrolling of wide block. Also I need to controll scrolling with mousewheel and buttons.

I have created working demo on codepen.

### [Demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/probil/pen/uDzfr/)

Here I use Endless.JS for loop scrolling (works with 2 divs and more) and jquery.mousewheel for mouse wheel support. Also I write some code for arrows. On hover -> block start scrolling with animation.

```
animate({scrollLeft:'+=40'}
```

This method works great with mouse wheel but I got some trouble with arrows. After I have scrolled first few divs other div become blinking and works like artifact in game :) (see demo)

Can you help me? Maybe I need to use some other method or lib?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably avoid jQuery.animate here. Not exactly sure what causes the problem, but using timeouts seems to work fine. That way, you also have more control over the delay and animation speed. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGbLB

```js
  var timeout;

  function loop_next(){
    timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
      container.scrollLeft(container.scrollLeft() + 2);
      loop_next();
    }, 20); 
  }
  function loop_prev(){
    timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
      container.scrollLeft(container.scrollLeft() - 2);
      loop_prev();
    }, 20);
  }
  function stop(){
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
```